# Why can't I comment on the Stack Overflow Blog even though I am signed in to Stack Overflow already?

Tags: feature-request, comments, login, blog

I was checking out this awesome article here 
https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/bye-bye-bullets-the-stack-overflow-developer-story-is-the-new-technical-resume/

and went over to make a comment and realized its asking me to log in via either

- Disqus
- Facebook
- Twitter
- Google

[image: Stack Overflow Blog comments screenshot]

I double checked to see that I was already logged in to Stack Overflow, so

- Why is it now requiring me to log in to a totally different system to comment on the blogs?
- Why do I need to identify myself via another system?

This seems totally counter productive as:

- What if I do not want to share my identity on one of those social
  networks to comment here
- When stackoverflow already has my login data, requiring me extra steps to identify myself again and that too with a totally different login system.

Answer (score 5):

The comments system is managed by Disqus. This is discussed in the [blog post about the blog's redesign](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/).

> There was really only one common solution we found that was compatible: Disqus.

The lack of Stack Exchange login is mentioned specifically.

> it meant we had to sacrifice a few things like Stack Exchange login capability. Those were things we could reasonably deal with.

Disqus doesn't provide a mechanism for integrating with the Stack Exchange login, so you'll need to authenticate using one of the supported methods.

Comment: Ohk, seems there were some decisions made at that time which caused that. Although it seems disqus has ability for Single Sign On - https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1104796-single-sign-on which explicitly mentions not having the need to get a disqus global account and the site can use their own database of users. Might be worth looking in to implement this in the future.